# flex blazeds response null for first time service call

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, blazeds

> I am using Flash Builder 4.5 with Blazeds service to develop flex
>   appliacation, here i used java for services and here i am getting
>   empty value from server side for first time service call, after that
>   from next service calling it gives correct result to me, I don't know
>   why i am getting null value for first time hitting the service. Here
>   for the first time hitting java service, the functionality is running
>   at java side but return value is null.

Please any one help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If we use LastResult for service response then I got this error, I used requestHandler for handling response and i got my response for first time itself.

```
Service.addEventListener("result", resultHandler);


private function resultHandler(evt:ResultEvent):void {
            var ac = evt.result;
          }
```